# Inferring Averages from Interval Data + Sums

Tags: interval-censoring

I have data on the number of firms reported in intervals by employment (e.g. 0-100, 100-200, etc. - $x_{1it},...,x_{nit}$), as well as the total employment ($y_{it}$) across firms in the sample- for multiple regions $i$ and years $t$. (Top-coding is not a problem in that I know the employment of the largest firms.)

I'm trying to think through whether there is a reasonable way to learn anything about the size distribution of firms based on this data.

One thought I had was a cross-sectional regression of total employment $y_{i}$ on the $x_{i}$, where the coefficients would represent the average sizes across all regions $i$ of firms in each interval. It seems this should be a case where a zero-constant regression is appropriate (since the functional form is an additive accounting identity).

I don't think this is a particularly original problem, but I am failing to find any sources to guide me. I would appreciate any tips, or pointers on the appropriate keywords for further searching!